# How to implement an EditText that overlaps on another EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is the image that I am trying to implement, but could not achieve the same.

Do I need to use animation or something else?

When user taps on password field the cuid field gets scalled and password will be enlarge and overlaps on cuid vice versa.

[image]

Code is here:

```
<ConstraintLayout.....>
    <!---CUID label>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_cab_management">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditText_CUID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/employee_id"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="@={vm.employeeID}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_input_Layout" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <!--  password Label -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayoutid"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayoutid"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutid">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:text="@={vm.emailOtp}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_input_Layout" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/appCompatButtonlogin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/sign_in_up_button_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

As well as used this animation:

```
 ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(
            view,
            view.getHeight(),
            view.getWidth(), 50, 50
    );
    resizeAnimation.setDuration(1 * 1000);
    resizeAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
```

Animation class:

```
public ResizeAnimation(View view, int startHeight, int startWidth, int targetHeight, int targetWidth) {
    this.view = view;

    this.startHeight = startHeight;
    this.startWidth = startWidth;

    this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
    this.targetWidth = targetWidth;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    int newHeight = (int) (startHeight + targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
    int newWidth = (int) (startWidth + targetWidth * interpolatedTime);
    //to support decent animation, change new heigt as Nico S. recommended in comments
    //int newHeight = (int) (startHeight+(targetHeight - startHeight) * interpolatedTime);
    view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
    view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
    view.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's called overlapping. But rather a very height elevation

Comment: @AhmadSattout How to implement that height elevation